How do you deploy to two chains in a foundry script?
I have two contracts that I want to deploy to two different EVM chains, how do I do that in a foundry script?
vm.startBroadcast(chainA);
contractA.deploy();
vm.stopBroadcast();

vm.startBroadcast(chainB);
contractB.deploy();
vm.stopBroadcast();


You can do multichain deployment using foundry as below
You can set up your foundry.toml file as below
[rpc_endpoints]
optimism = "https://opt-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/<api key>"
goerli = "https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/<api key>"

Below is the suggestion for multichain deployment.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "../lib/forge-std/src/Script.sol";

contract Try {}

contract MultipleDeployment is Script {
    function run() external {
        vm.startBroadcast();

        // create and select for optimism
        vm.createSelectFork(vm.rpcUrl("optimism"));
        address t1 = address(new Try());
        console.log(t1);

        // create and select fork for goerli
        vm.createSelectFork(vm.rpcUrl("goerli"));
        address t2 = address(new Try());
        console.log(t2);

        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}


For reference you can head to
https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/2519

I'll have to give this a whirl. But does the createSelectFork not act as a fork then? Seems to be a bit of a misnomer. Would a better name becreateOrSelectRpc?

Ah, got it. There was another issue that I thought was due to the vm.createSelectFork keyword that was unrelated.

I meet error when use your code, 'script failed: cannot select forks during a broadcast'

For those who have the cannot select forks during a broadcast, mention the RPC URL outside the vm broadcast block and then try (there will be two start and stop broadcast).

    string[7] memory networks = [
        'sepolia',
        'optimismSepolia',
        'arbitrumSepolia',
        'baseSepolia',
        'lineaSepolia',
        'blastSepolia',
        'polygonAmoy',
    ];

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < networks.length; i++) {
        string memory network = networks[i];
        vm.createSelectFork(vm.rpcUrl(network));

        vm.startBroadcast(privateKey);
        _run();
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }

Here is my multi chain deploy code.
